# language translation in UTF-8 or unicode

Tags: utf, unicode-string

In my Chinese properties file I have a code like :

```
FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD_TITLE =\u5fd8\u8bb0 ID/\u5bc6\u7801
```

I have tried with native to ASCII of java software

Now I have to modify it. I am not able to understand whether it is Unicode or other. I have used native to ascii & other tools to find it out. But I did not find. Can any one help me to understand which type of code is this??

Answer (score 0):

It is unicode.  I'm assuming windows - different ball game if it is linux.

Start the charmap utility that comes with windows.
Change to font to Arial Unicode MS.
Select Advanced View.
Type in each of the \u codes and click select.
You will end up with something like

忘记密码

Copy that and paste in Google translate.  Change the other side to English - it will say Forgot Password.